# javax.mail.Session constructor "is not visible"

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

This is almost the same as the Google App Engine code for JavaMail use.  [Link](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail.html)

It gives a Session constructor not visible error.  The other imports seem fine so why is this happening to Session?

```
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

Properties props = new Properties();
Session session = new Session(props, null);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Session` has no public constructor; you need to use the static `getInstance()` or `getDefaultInstance()` methods. See [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/mail/Session.html#getInstance%28java.util.Properties,%20javax.mail.Authenticator%29).